# Select Row values based on values in another row

Tags: sql-server, sorting, subquery

I have a table that has an auto-incrementing identity "Reference" field and a pair of other fields that determine the sort order. What I need to do is find the 'next' item in the table when sorted based on the pair of fields based on the reference field of an initial item.

So my data looks like this when sorted by SortParent.SortChild:

```
Reference  SortParent  SortChild  Data
------------------------------------------
9          1           2          Fred
7          1           3          Jim
11         1           4          Sheila
4          2           1          Micro
5          2           2          Archimedes
12         2           3          Electron
```

So in this example the "Jim" row (Reference=7) comes after "Fred" (Reference=9) even though it's reference is smaller.

So i want to be able to find which row comes after Fred by searching based on Jim's reference

At the moment in code I do a query to find the values for Fred's row:

```
SELECT SortParent,SortChild From MyTable WHERE Reference=9
```

Which returns 1,2. Then do a search for the first row that comes after 1,2:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE ((SortParent=1 and SortChild>2) OR (SortParent>2))
ORDER BY SortParent,SortChild
```

Which will therefore come back with the row having reference 7 and sort values 1,3

I'm pretty sure this can be done in a single query, but i'm stumped on the best way.

Incidentally, if anyone has any suggestions on alternate way of handling the two part sort columns that would make this easier, please feel free to help!

Comment: Which version of `SQL SERVER` you are using

Comment: We're targeting SQL Server 2008R2 and higher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe You are looking at the LEAD or LAG windowed function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh213125.aspx

```
SELECT 
    NextReference 
FROM 
    (SELECT
        reference 
        , LEAD(reference, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY SortParent,SortChild) AS NextReference   
        , *
    FROM 
         mytable 
    ) newTable
    WHERE 
        reference = 9
```

I used LEAD, but try it with LAG if you are looking in the other direction for the row

I havn't tested this particular query, so my not be syntactically sound, but let me know if you have any troubles with it and I'll go over it a bit more once I'm back at my desk

EDIT: Used the wrong sql from your question as my base

EDIT2: Put the lead into a subquery to allow us to query on it

Comment: Thats a very neat function - I'd not seen it before. Unfortunately I can't get it to work - if i remove the `WHERE` clause then I do see all the items in the correct order, but with the `WHERE` clause in it's not returning a value (just the default of 0)  - I think this is because the `WHERE` is filtering the table before the `LEAD` can then walk the resulting set - so there is only a single row so it can't offset by +1 to read the next one.

Comment: @PeterJarrett Ah, yes, you, are right. I've edited my answer so that the lead is inside a subquery, with an outer select selecting on the reference, That should do the trick for you!